# submit not firing on first click in react app

Tags: reactjs, validation, onsubmit

I have a `bootstrap react form` with validation, and I am using the `email.js library` to send emails to the client side instead of `axios http request` (this is to prevent sending data to the serve-side)  `onSubmit` only sends on double click due to the if statement function checking if validation is true. If I remove this function the onSubmit will fire on one click but will bypass validation checks.

Is there another way I can write this code? Possibly with `useEffect()`? The onSubmit usually is for firing the validation function, however, the email.js library uses the onSubmit to send data which forces me to make custom validation forms and I am not able to be successful to fire the onSubmit with one click

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Col, Button, Form, Card, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";

 const refForm = useRef();

//for validity
const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

// email.js to send data to client
const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

setFormSubmitted(true);

const form = e.currentTarget;
if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
}

setValidated(true);
 if (validated === true) {

 // email.js code here
 console.log("email.js has sent the email")
 }
};

 return (

          <Form
            ref={refForm}
            onSubmit={sendEmail}
            autoComplete="on"
            noValidate
            validated={validated}
          >
            <Form.Label>Full Name*</Form.Label>
            <Form.Group>
              <InputGroup hasValidation>
                <Form.Control
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  minLength={3}
                  maxLength={20}
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Full name required
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </InputGroup>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Label>Email Address*</Form.Label>
            <Form.Group>
              <InputGroup hasValidation>
                <Form.Control
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter a valid email format
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
              </InputGroup>

          <Button
            type="submit"
            value="send"
          >
            SUBMIT
          </Button>
        </Form>
```

Comment: Rather than checking if your state variable `validated` is `true` before running your email logic, could you not return from your `sendEmail` function if `form.checkValidity() === false`, as currently it looks like your form will always be considered valid.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested before I posed this question and the result was successful on mouse click, but bypassed all validation checks

Answer (score 0):

simple answer, needed to separate `sendEmail()` from the validation function using `onChange` event. I also needed to create `checkString()` to check string was empty and pass through the validation function.

```
  // check if string is empty
  const checkString = () => {
    // console.log("name", fullName)
    if (fullName.length === 0) {
      console.log("empty");
      setTest(true);
    }
  };

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
    //email.js code 
    }

    const validateEmail = (e) => {
    checkString();

    const form = e.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    }
    setValidated(true);
  };

          <Form
        onSubmit={sendEmail}
        onChange={validateEmail }
      >
```